# Query recommendation

Tags: sql, db2

It would be good if someone can provide some recommendation for rewriting the below query. I have a table with 2 million records, I need to find out duplicates on two separate keys(ID an DNM) and if it have duplicate then need to delete it. I write two separate query for it as shown below. Is there anyway to make it as single query and also rewrite it in a better way, as this query is really taking time.

```
DELETE FROM TABLEA
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEA WHERE TYPE <> 'A'
GROUP BY ID having count(*)>1) AND TYPE <> 'A'; 

 

DELETE FROM TABLEA WHERE DNM IN (SELECT DNM FROM TABLEA WHERE TYPE <> 'A'
GROUP BY DNM HAVING COUNT(*) >1) AND TYPE <> 'A';
```

Comment: I can't speak for db2, but in MySQL it would almost certainly be quicker to create a new table retaining only those rows you wish to keep, and then replace the old table, and the re-index the new one

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Why do you use the same constant in both `TYPE` inequalities in the 1-st statement, but different constants in the 2-nd? Moreover, you don't delete duplicates there. You delete complete group, rather than leaving one record from each group of duplicates...

Comment: Sample data and desired results results would help.  For instance, your description mentions nothing about `type`, but that seems important based on the sample code.  Also, does your table have a primary key?

Comment: Hi All, I have edited my post for the type value.. It was a typo mistake. Also if there are duplicates, I need to delete the complete groups. Regarding type in the table I have two set of records, one with TYPE A and other with TYPE B. I need to find duplicates and delete group only for TYPE A records. My table only have a business key which is a sequence generated number

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use ROW_NUMBER for both columns in question, like so:

```
WITH deduplicate AS (
SELECT
   ID AS unique_id,
   DNM AS unique_dnm,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS id_row,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DNM ORDER BY DNM) AS dnm_row
FROM
   TABLEA
) 
SELECT
   * INTO
     TABLEB
FROM
   TABLEA
      INNER JOIN
         deduplicate
      ON ID = unique_id
      AND DNM = unique_dnm
WHERE
   id_row = 1
AND
   dnm_row = 1
;
```

Note that I am recommending that you create a new table using an INNER JOIN. This will get rid of the duplicate rows without making two separate DELETE statements.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to delete duplicates you want to use a query like this

```
    DELETE FROM (
        SELECT
             PK_COLS
        ,    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PK_COLS) AS RN
        FROM
           YOUR_TABLE
    )
    WHERE RN > 1
```

it is usually much faster than any other method